# Why does concatenating with an empty list return a list but not when concatenating with new list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a rather newb question:

Doing this

```
 var emptyList = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<int>(), 1).ToList();
 var nonEmptyList = new List<int> { 1 };
 var joinedList = emptyList.Select(x => x.Concat(nonEmptyList)).ToList();
```

returns a non empty list

[image]

However this return an empty list

```
 var emptyList = new List<List<int>>();
 var nonEmptyList = new List<int> { 1 };
 var joinedList = emptyList.Select(x => x.Concat(nonEmptyList)).ToList();
```

How is Linq able to concatenate items from the `empty` list with the `nonEmpty` list when the selected items are empty lists themselves? and then why doesn't it work when I try it with a new list in the second example?

Thanks

Comment: Your first 'emptyList' is an enumerable containing one empty list (one element). Your second 'emptyList' is an empty list of lists (zero elements). Seeing this, you should be able to see how it gets to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enumerable.Repeat` returns an `IEnumerable<IResult>`. After calling `ToList`, it becomes a `List<IResult>`. What is `TResult` then? It is the type of the argument you passed to `Repeat` - `IEnumerable<int>`. So altogether, `emptyList` is a `List<IEnumerable<int>>`.

Now, is `emptyList` empty?

No, but the `IEnumerable<int>` inside it, *is*.

`emptyList` has an element. The element is an empty `IEnumerable<int>`. Why? Because you told it to `Repeat` an empty enumerable once. An "empty enumerable" does not mean nothing. Repeating an empty enumerable once gets you one empty enumerable, not nothingness.

After you understand this it's pretty clear what's happening here. You concatenated the empty enumerable to the `1` and that makes the `joinedList` to be `{1}`.

In the second case, `new List<List<int>>()` creates an empty list that has not lists in it, so `Select` does not do anything here.

Answer (score 0):

`EmptyList.Select` iterates over an.... empty list. Hence, the result will also be empty.